# Что будет выведено в консоль? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

Что будет выведено в консоль? JavaScript[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что мешает запустить данный код и посмотреть что произойдёт?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` автоматически обновляется при изменении dom, потому вы увидите разные цифры, если вы об этом.

Answer (score 2):

%)

```js
let arr1 = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
let arr2 = document.querySelectorAll('a');

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
console.log(arr1.length, arr2.length);
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
```